# Can Google App Engine kill an instance which is waiting for an HTTP response?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Can Google App Engine Auto Scaling kill an instance while it is waiting for a HTTP response from a server? Or is Auto Scaling intelligent enough to only kill an instance after the instance has done all of it's work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app engine scheduler won't kill an instance while the instance its serving or waiting for a response since it only kill idle instances. If the instance it's waiting for a response when the scheduler decides to kill the instance the scheduler will give 30 second of margin to complete, and new requests immediately return 404. You can see more detailed information in the App Engine [How Instances are Managed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/how-instances-are-managed#shutdown) documentation